# the most performant way finding an item in array within a range of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for something like the built-in [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), but I want to be able to search starting from a given index, without creating a new shallow copy of range of items from this array.

possibilities:

- using Array.prototype.find with no starting index.
- using [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then .find. something like `arr.slice(startIndedx).find(...)`. creating shallow copy.
- writing my own find implementation using for loop that start looking from given index.
- using [lodash.find()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find). but I care about bundle size and lodash is quite heavy. I actually prefer avoiding any kind of third-party packages.

here are some performance test results :

```
const SIZE = 1000000
const START_I = 800000
const ItemVal = 900000
...
find: average time: 12.1ms
findSlice: average time: 2.48ms
findLodash: average time: 0.26ms
myFind: average time: 0.26ms
```

surprisingly enough its seems that that native .find performed worse even with starting index 0 :

```
const SIZE = 1000000
const START_I = 0
const ItemVal = 900000
...
find: average time: 12.61ms
findSlice: average time: 17.51ms
findLodash: average time: 1.93ms
myFind: average time: 2.17ms
```

for array size 1000000 , starting index of 0 and the correct position is 900000, `Array.prototype.find()` preformed `12.61ms` vs `2.17ms` of the simple for loop search(!). am I missing something?

the test code is:

```js
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
const _ = require('lodash')

const SIZE = 1000000
const START_I = 0
const ItemVal = 900000

let arr = Array(SIZE).fill(0)
arr = arr.map((a, i) => i)

const myFind = (arr, func, startI) => {
    for (let i = startI; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (func(arr[i])) return arr[i]
    }
    return -1
}

const functions = {
    find: () => arr.find(a => a === ItemVal), // looking at all array - no starting index
    findSlice: () => arr.slice(START_I).find(a => a === ItemVal),
    findLodash: () => _.find(arr, a => a === ItemVal, START_I),
    myFind: () => myFind(arr, a => a === ItemVal, START_I),
}

const repeat = 100
const test_find = () => {
    for (let [name, func] of Object.entries(functions)) {
        let totalTime = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            let t_current = performance.now()
            func()
            totalTime += performance.now() - t_current
        }
        console.log(`${name}: average time: ${Math.round(totalTime / repeat * 100) / 100}ms`)
    }

}
test_find()
```

what is the best way to find an item in an array stating looking from an index? and also, how does `Array.prototype.find` perform worse than my own simple for loop implementation of find?

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: @NinaScholz no.

Comment: @EliavLouski what speaks against using a hash table/ Map which would always beat list searches?

Comment: If you work with such operation, You need to use HashMap, or some kind  of balanced tree, You don't need to count every time,  just use a `count` state, and modify it (`count += 1`)